# std::function in template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I was trying to write a template function which can accept functor as parameter and call it afterwards. The program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
R call(function<R(Args...)> fun, Args... args)
{
    cout << "call@ " << __LINE__ <<endl;
    return fun(args...);
}

int main()
{
    cout << call(std::plus<int>(),1,2) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The G++ compplains:

```
g++ -c -Wall -std=c++0x -I../include a.cpp -o a.o
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:16:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘call(std::plus<int>, int, int)’
a.cpp:16:38: note: candidate is:
a.cpp:7:3: note: template<class R, class ... Args> R call(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>, Args ...)
a.cpp:7:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:16:38: note:   ‘std::plus<int>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>’
make: *** [a.o] Error 1
```

I suppose `std::plus<int>()` could be deduced to `std::function<int(int,int)>`, but it didn't. Why was that? GCC is `gcc version 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2) (GCC)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I suppose std::plus() could be deduced to std::function

No. It could not be deduced given that you have passed an object of type `std::plus<int>`.

In your case, **you do not need to use `std::function`**, as generally you would mostly use it when storing different functions/function objects that can be called with a specific signature.

With that, you can just have your `call` function accept the function/function object directly, with its original type deduced, without using `std::function`. Also, you might also want to use perfect forwarding when accepting the parameters and use `std::forward` when passing them as arguments to the function/function object. You should also use the return type of your function as the return type of `call`. Use C++11's trailing return type with `decltype` for that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
auto call(R fun, Args&&... args) -> decltype(fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    cout << "call@ " << __LINE__ <<endl;
    return fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    cout << call(std::plus<int>(),1,2) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[LIVE CODE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac26b7efc9329d9c)

---

As what @Jan Hudec has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606427/stdfunction-in-template-function/18606655#comment27386567_18606655), `__LINE__` in there will always result the same in all calls to `call`, whatever function is passed.

Comment: +1 though you missed the uselessness of that `__LINE__`. It will print the _same_ line for _all_ calls.

Comment: I'm tempted to add emphasis: "**you do not need to use `std::function`**". `std::function` seems to be way overused.

Answer (score 3):

It can't deduce the template arguments.

I would recommend changing the function signature like so:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto call(F fun, Args... args )
    -> decltype( fun(args...) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Most implicit conversions are not considered when deducing template arguments. Certainly not user-defined ones. So even if `plus` is convertible to `function`, it doesn't make a difference.